# Why can Professor Xavier walk in Secret Wars?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, secret-wars

In [*Secret Wars* #1](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_1), Professor Xavier is transported to Battleworld with his wheelchair, and Mr. Fantastic states in [issue #3](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_3) that he wasn't originally in it (I assume he was in bed or something).

[image]

> Mr. Fantastic: Professor X said he wasn't in his wheelchair when he disappeared, though he arrived here in it! It's as though the Beyonder "fixed" little things that seemed to be wrong, or missing!

Yet after issue #1, he's walking around with his wheelchair nowhere in sight. Spider-Man even comments on it.

[image]

> Spider-Man: *(Thinking)* Boy, it's still weird seeing Professor Xavier not in a wheelchair--!

How is Professor Xavier able to walk? Did I miss something in *Secret Wars*? Or was something going on in the X-Men series at the time that made him able to walk?

Comment: It was in issue #2 that Mr. Fantastic made his comment regarding Xavier’s wheelchair

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.supermegamonkey.net/chronocomic/entries/marvel_super_heroes_secret_war.shtml), he overcame the mental block (his legs had been repaired some time before) in the issues right before Secret Wars.

> Although Professor X theoretically has had the ability to walk for some time now, it was only in the issues of X-Men and New Mutants that took place directly before Secret Wars that he was able to overcome the mental blocks and actually start walking without pain. Additionally, while Storm has been the leader of the field team, the X-Men's first and greatest field leader Cyclops is back in the picture for this series. So there's a lot of debate about who should be leading the team.

According to the [Marvel wiki entry](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Charles_Xavier_(Earth-616)), his body was restored (mind transferred into a newer, younger, clone body) in *Uncanny X-Men #167*. Between #171-175, he attempted to walk, but felt intense pain when he tried to use his legs.

*[New Mutants #14](http://www.therealgentlemenofleisure.com/2012/12/x-amining-new-mutants-14.html)* is where he is first shown walking, with the reveal apparently being him getting up to dance with Illyana after she defeated S'ym.
[image: Professor Xavier standing and hugging Illyana]

In [Issue #180](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_180), we see him [walking and playing basketball](http://www.therealgentlemenofleisure.com/2012/12/x-amining-uncanny-x-men-180.html) before is abducted to Battleworld at the end.

> After months of practice, Charles Xavier has managed to beat the psychosomatic feedback his mental powers had created preventing him from walking in his new body. He decides to enjoy this newly acquired ability to playing basket ball.

[image: Professor Xavier playing basketbacll in *Uncanny X-men #180*]

....

> When Kitty tries to alert the Professor telepathically, she cannot reach him as at that very moment, the Professor, Colossus, Wolverine and Storm are drawn to Central Park. There a giant construct has appeared in the location and as they all approach it they are teleported away to a far off place....
>
> The fate of the X-Men continues in Marvel Super Heroes Secret Wars #1....